# How to deal with large amounts of data from django based IOT projects

Tags: python, django, database, iot

I'm working on a django IOT related dashboard style project. I have a question related to the scale of the project. Let's say that there are 30 or more raspberry pi's or ardunios and you want to get the location and some other data off of them and store it in a database. How would one go about designing a database for a system at such a large scale.

Comment: 30 clients is not large scale. Did you mean to say that you'll be storing a lot of data such as new location data every few seconds? Please add more information in your question.

Comment: Yeah I should have elaborated my question more. It will be trying to store location data every few seconds, I was going over the DBMS normalisation techniques, they seem to be useful, but I'm having a hard time trying to understand how one handels with such large amounts of data with relative order associated to them.

Comment: You may find something helpful on this page: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188667/best-database-and-table-design-for-billions-of-rows-of-data